# What is the raku equivalent of @INC, please?

Tags: raku

I go

```
export RAKULIB="/GitHub/raku-Units/lib"
```

and then

```
echo $RAKULIB
/GitHub/raku-Units/lib
```

But when I run `perl6 t/01-basic.t`

```
use v6;
 
use Test;

plan 3;
 
lives-ok {
    use Units <m>;
    ok @Units::UNITS.elems > 0;
    ok (0m).defined;
} 
   
done-testing;
```

I still get an error

```
===SORRY!===
Could not find Units at line 8 in:
    /Users/--me--/.perl6
    /usr/local/Cellar/rakudo-star/2018.01/share/perl6/site
    /usr/local/Cellar/rakudo-star/2018.01/share/perl6/vendor
    /usr/local/Cellar/rakudo-star/2018.01/share/perl6
    CompUnit::Repository::AbsolutePath<140707489084448>
    CompUnit::Repository::NQP<140707463117264>
    CompUnit::Repository::Perl5<140707463117304>
```

In Perl 5 I would have used `print "@INC";` to see what paths are searched for the lib before the error is thrown. Using `say flat $*REPO.repo-chain.map(*.loaded);` either is before it loads or after it throws the exception.

Any help would be much appreciated - or maybe a hint on what to put in `~/.raku` as I can't get a symlink to work either.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352971/dynamic-variable-inc-not-found ?

Comment: Sidenote: as an alternative to PERL6LIB you can also `use lib 'lib/dir';`

Comment: ah yes - thanks @donaldh - i have been relying on editing all the use lib line s in source ... thus the need for -I

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message itself is telling you what the library paths available are. You are failing to print them because you are expecting a run time action ( `say` ) to take place before a compile time error -- you could print out `$*REPO` at compile time, but again the exception is already showing you what you wanted.

```
$ RAKULIB="/GitHub/raku-Units/lib" raku -e 'BEGIN say $*REPO.repo-chain; use Foo;'
(file#/GitHub/raku-Units/lib inst#/Users/ugexe/.perl6 inst#/Users/ugexe/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.08/install/share/perl6/site inst#/Users/ugexe/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.08/install/share/perl6/vendor inst#/Users/ugexe/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.08/install/share/perl6 ap# nqp# perl5#)
===SORRY!===
Could not find Foo at line 1 in:
    /GitHub/raku-Units/lib
    /Users/ugexe/.perl6
    /Users/ugexe/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.08/install/share/perl6/site
    /Users/ugexe/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.08/install/share/perl6/vendor
    /Users/ugexe/.rakudobrew/moar-2018.08/install/share/perl6
    CompUnit::Repository::AbsolutePath<140337382425072>
    CompUnit::Repository::NQP<140337350057496>
    CompUnit::Repository::Perl5<140337350057536>
```

You can see `/GitHub/raku-Units/lib` is showing up in the available paths, which is unlike your example. I'd question if your shell/env is actually setup correctly.

Comment: Thank you @ugexe your answer is absolutely right - I was using two terminal windows and had not added PERL6LIB to my .profile and restarted the shell so kept failing in the 2nd window. Now hanging head in red-face shame...

Comment: Hi @p6steve If you accept ugexe's answer then your question becomes a good thing so you can s/hanging head in red-face shame/holding head high in SO contributor game/. :)